# yeoman permission issue with nodejs and angular

Tags: node.js, angularjs, ubuntu

I am trying to start an angular web app with yeoman but I get permission issue when trying to install the new generator. I can bypass and install generator with sudo but then I get the permission errors when running

```
**yo** angular
```

I deduce its because its trying to access npm modules that are global which the current user doesnt have permissions for, and I cant  run Yo with sudo. I have done a lot of google searches and they all involve some type of hack with the NODE_PATH in the .bashrc or moving the node modules to the home directory. Has anyone found a simple solution for this issue.

Below is my problem in screenshots:

[image]

**yo** installs fine

[image]

when i try to install the generator without sudo complains..
[image]

install with sudo passes.
[image]

then finally when I try to run **yo** angular it breaks.. I believe its because **yo** runs as user and I have installed everything with sudo privileges. How can I get past this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it breaks, I guess, is because the whole directory tree was created as super-user.

The hacks you mentioned about using `NODE_PATH` and the home directory are not hacks. They exist for this same very reason. To tell node where to look for packages. And `.bashrc` is the place where you are supposed to change this kind shell variables.

Say you added `~/.node_modules` to you `NODE_PATH`, then you can install all "global" in there. You could also change the permissions on `/usr/local`. But on linux world that is not recommended.

I also strongly recommend in not using global install with npm. Using -g and `npm link` is handy when developing but you shouldn't count on them. You can introduce subtle bugs in your code when you forget to add a package on you `package.json` but it is installed globally.

Instead of installing it globally, you can find all the packages executable on `./node_modules/.bin/` directory.

But lets say you don't want to be typing `./node_modules/.bin/yo` all the time, you could create an alias on your `.bashrc`.

```
alias yo="$PWD/node_modules/.bin/yo"
```

and it would work like expected, and if there is no yo package installed, you get an error.